# Gradle single-project pluginManagement block not working (Kotlin DSL)

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I need to change a multi-project build to a single-project build, as there is and only ever will be one project in this repo.  Currently, in `settings.gradle`, I have a custom plugin repo that currently uses a `pluginManagement` block with `resolutionStrategy` and my list of repo's:

```
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == 'com.meanwhileinhell.plugin') {
                useModule('com.meanwhileinhell:gradle-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }

        // Meanwhileinhell repo
        maven {
            url "s3://mvn.meanwhileinhell.com/releases"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey s3_access_key
                secretKey s3_access_secret
            }
        }
    }

    plugins {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

However, deleting `settings.gradle` and moving this block into my `build.gradle.kts` (Kotlin DSL) seems to do nothing.  I've tried wrapping in a

```
configurations {
    all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachPlugin {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and also

```
settings {
    pluginManagement {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachPlugin {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found a SO answer that used `settingsEvaluated` in order to get the `settings` object, but again this was a no go.

Currently my `build.gradle.kts` looks like this, without pulling any plugin in from my repo:

```
val springBootVersion: String by project

group = "com.meanwhileinhell.myapp"
version = "$version"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven ("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot")
    maven ("https://repo.spring.io/milestone")
    maven ("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")

    maven {
        url = uri("s3://mvn.meanwhileinhell.com/releases")
        credentials(AwsCredentials::class) {
            accessKey = (project.property("s3_access_key") as String)
            secretKey = (project.property("s3_access_secret") as String)
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    base
    eclipse
    idea
    java
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    // Load but don't apply to root project
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "1.5.14.RELEASE" apply false
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Whenever I try to add a plugin id like `id("com.meanwhileinhell.plugin.hell2java") version "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"` I get an error that looks like it isn't even looking in my S3 location:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.meanwhileinhell.plugin.hell2java', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.meanwhileinhell.plugin.hell2java:com.meanwhileinhell.plugin.hell2java.gradle.plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

**EDIT !!!! -----------------------**

I've just found this in the Gradle docs:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management

> The pluginManagement {} block may only appear in either the settings.gradle file....

Looks like I'm going down the wrong way entirely, so will look into the initialisation script route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have missed something about the file structure.

In the Groovy DSL, you have the following files:

- build.gradle
- settings.gradle
- init.gradle

In the Kotlin DSL, you have the same files but with the .kts extension:

- build.gradle.kts
- settings.gradle.kts
- init.gradle.kts

The Kotlin DSL doesn't differ to the Groovy DSL in where to put things. `pluginManagement` need to go in to the settings file, so for Kotlin that would be `settings.gradle.kts`. If you are in doubt, look at the documentation. For almost all code examples, you can switch between Groovy and Kotlin DSL to see how to do it (and which files they are supposed go to into).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BjørnVester.  Isn't the `settings.gradle[.kts]` file only to be used for multi-project builds?

Comment: I always have it, even for stand-alone projects. One of the other things you can change through it is the project name (if you don't want to rely on defaulting to the folder name).

Comment: The settings.gradle_[.kts] script is evaluated before any build.gradle[.kts] script. When the setting.gradle[.kts] script is evaluated, you'll see that "project" is not defined. It really has nothing to do specifically with multi-projects, other than its useful for setting things up applicable to all projects before they get evaluated.